# How to link a SQL query with another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have a Query That returns me the states abbreviations and the counts the query is

```
 SELECT state, COUNT( state )
FROM Stripe_Transactions
WHERE (
state <> "0"
)
AND (
state IS NOT NULL
)
AND (
state <> " "
)
AND (
UPPER( Usertype ) = "PARENT"
)
GROUP BY state
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now, I want to Match this query results with another table `STATES` where I have  full forms of the States.Columns of States table are -stateID, StateName.
Current OUTPUT

[image: Current Output]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Could not find the answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume your `MATCH` here means `JOIN` in `SQL`.

If that is the case, you can put your code in a temporary table then left join with your `STATES` table.

In fact, you can put in a subquery and `left_join`, however, I assume your are a fresher so gonna do in a simple way.

```
SELECT state, COUNT( state )

INTO #a         --temporary table (I'm using SQL Server)

FROM Stripe_Transactions
WHERE (state <> "0")
  AND (state IS NOT NULL)
  AND (state <> " ")
  AND (UPPER(Usertype) = "PARENT")
GROUP BY state
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is probably your `state` table

```
state_id  state_name
AK        Alaska
AL        Alabama
MS        Mississippi
NM        New Mexico
```

This is your `CURRENT_OUTPUT` that was put in a temporary table named `#a`:

```
state_id    your_count
AK          15
AL          20
MS          21
NM          100
```

Try this out:

```
select state.state_id, 
       state.stateName, 
       #a.your_count  
from state
left join    
#a
on state.state_id = #a.state_id
```

RESULT:

```
state_id     state_name        your_count
AK           Alaska            15
AL           Alabama           20
MS           Mississippi       21
NM           New Mexico        100
```

Comment: heyy Thanks! but its giving me an errror `  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Stripe_Transactions WHERE (state <> "0") AND (state IS NOT' at line 4`

Comment: @DakshAngaraj, hey since I am using SQL Server so there will be some small differences. I suppose the problem is at the `temporary table`, maybe you should check this document https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/